# Is there a way to import Xcode key bindings into AppCode

Tags: xcode, appcode

I need to start using AppCode as Xcode doesn't support red-green-refactor workflow. However the IntelliJ key bindings are really annoying - is there a way of importing Xcode keybinding wholesale instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AppCode already has **Xcode** keymap bundled, all you need is to select it in `Preferences` | `Keymap`:

[image: Xcode keymap]

Comment: Is there a way to import IntelliJ key bindings into Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

If you go Preferences->Keymap there is a keymaps flipmenu in the upper left. It contains a lot of default keymaps, one is Xcode.